# Convert C# to VB With Finding And Attaching to 64 Bit Processes

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Alright, So I Have a Program that was Built into C# that has the ability to Successfully Attach To a 64 Bit Process; I.E Like Chrome when Running Flash.

Here is a Code snippet in C#:

```
public int Chrome()
    {
        Process[] chrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        foreach (Process subchrome in chrome)
        {
            List<string> modules = EnumProcessModules((uint)subchrome.Id);
            foreach (string submodule in modules)
            {
                if (submodule.Contains("pepflashplayer"))
                {
                    return subchrome.Id;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

How Can I Rewrite this to Work in VB and still attach to 64 Bit Processes? 
How Can I Make it Attach To a 64 Bit Process or how can I make it check if the process is 64 Bit?

Comment: not sure where your definition of EnumProcessModules is but you should be using an intptr i believe instead of an unsigned integer

Comment: Assuming you mean VB.NET, why not leave it as C# in a class library and reference it from the VB.NET app.  If you mean VB 6 or something, then... you don't.  I believe earlier VBs are 32-bit only so I don't think it would ever work.

Comment: @Ctznkane525  That method might be using `EnumProcesses`, which takes a `uint` as `processID` parameter. But, it would be a bit weird, since you just need `Process.GetProcessById` and then return a `List<string>` of the `ProcessModuleCollection.ProcessModule.ModuleName`. The OP will probably come back to translate that too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: (cheated: used this http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
Public Function Chrome() As Integer
Dim chrome As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")

For Each subchrome As Process In chrome
    Dim modules As List(Of String) = EnumProcessModules(CUInt(subchrome.Id))

    For Each submodule As String In modules

        If submodule.Contains("pepflashplayer") Then
            Return subchrome.Id
        End If
    Next
Next

Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: You need to rename the 'chrome' local or the 'Chrome' method (VB doesn't differentiate between 'Chrome' and 'chrome').

Comment: very true.  As I stated above though, I cheated & just used an online converter...